# "No style rules found on passed Component" when unit testing direct child of styled component using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Here is the styled `li` for my component:

```
const Tab = styled.li`
  margin: 0px 60px;
  color: black;
  & > button {
    border: none;
    padding: 28px 0px;
    font-weight: 600px;
  }
`;
```

And here is the unit test that's failing:

```
const tabItems = [
  {
    label: 'Test 1',
    id: 'tab1',
  },
  {
    label: 'Test 2',
    id: 'tab2',
  },
];
describe('Tabs styling tests', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('should have font-weight 600', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Tabs tabItems={tabItems} selected="test1" />);

    expect(getByText('Test 1')).toHaveStyleRule('font-weight', '600');
  });
});
```

I am getting `No style rules found on passed Component` for any css style that I try to test for that button. 
The tests pass for any `.parentElement` styling that is tested. 
For eg. `expect(getByText('Test 1').parentElement).toHaveStyleRule('color', 'black');` works just fine.

How do I test the direct child of a styled component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to get this to work finally:

```
it('should have font-weight 600', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Tabs tabItems={tabItems} selected="test1" />);

  expect(getByText('Test 1').parentElement).toHaveStyleRule(
    'font-weight', 
    '600',
    { modifier: css`> button` }
  );
});
```

Source: https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/blob/master/README.md#tohavestylerule

Comment: this doesn't explain anything?